# Canvas Code behaving differently in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

The purpose of code is to display some letters in the center of window. And when cursor is brought close to it the letters move in different direction. This behaviour works fine in Chrome but in firefox, when cursor is brought on the letter, it moves to top-left corner. To see live effect, visit: https://prakashaditya369.github.io.

Canvas Code:

```
/*Display LEIBTON in Homepage using Canvas*/
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Resizing
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 5;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 5;

//Initializing Variables.
var gap = 60
var vGap = 30
var particles;
var collide_limit = 40;
var velocity = 20;
var angular_velocity = 30;
var working_factor = {
    space_typed: false,
    space_needed: false
}

var mouse = {
    timestamp: 0,
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0,
    prevX: 0,
    prevY: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    clicked: false
}

//Functions required For Collision Tasks

//Function to find Distance between two points
function distance(point1x, point1y, point2x, point2y) {
    return Math.sqrt((point1x - point2x) * (point1x - point2x) + (point1y - point2y) * (point1y - point2y))
}

//Function to find rotated velocities.
function rotate(velocity, angle) {
    const rotatedVelocities = {
        x: velocity.x * Math.cos(angle) - velocity.y * Math.sin(angle),
        y: velocity.x * Math.sin(angle) + velocity.y * Math.cos(angle)
    };

    return rotatedVelocities;
}

//Function to resolve collision
/*Code used from somewhere else.*/
function resolveCollision(particle, otherParticle) {
    const xVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.x - otherParticle.velocity.x;
    const yVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.y - otherParticle.velocity.y;

    const xDist = otherParticle.x - particle.x;
    const yDist = otherParticle.y - particle.y;

    // Prevent accidental overlap of particles
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {

        // Grab angle between the two colliding particles
        const angle = -Math.atan2(otherParticle.y - particle.y, otherParticle.x - particle.x);

        // Store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        const m1 = particle.mass;
        const m2 = otherParticle.mass;

        // Velocity before equation
        const u1 = rotate(particle.velocity, angle);
        const u2 = rotate(otherParticle.velocity, angle);

        // Velocity after 1d collision equation
        const v1 = {
            x: u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            y: u1.y
        };
        const v2 = {
            x: u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2),
            y: u2.y
        };

        // Final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        const vFinal1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
        const vFinal2 = rotate(v2, -angle);

        // Swap particle velocities for realistic bounce effect
        particle.velocity.x = vFinal1.x;
        particle.velocity.y = vFinal1.y;

        otherParticle.velocity.x = vFinal2.x;
        otherParticle.velocity.y = vFinal2.y;
    }
}

//Function to write Heading.
function writeHeading() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#424874"
    ctx.font = '30px Raleway';
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.fillText("Personal Website of Aditya Prakash", window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 + vGap)
}

//Function to write instruction to unjumble.
function writeJumble() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#424874"
    ctx.font = '15px Raleway';
    ctx.textAlign = "center"
    ctx.fillText("Damn it! LeibTon got Jumbled, Press Space to Unjumble", window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 + vGap + 40)
}


//Particle Class.
function Particle(letter, x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
    this.mass = 10;
    this.d2x = 0;
    this.d2y = 0;
    this.basey = y;
    this.basex = x;
    this.drotate = 0;
    this.ddrotate = 0;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.letter = letter;
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.font = '100px "Playfair Display"';
        ctx.fillStyle = "#7981AF";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y)
        ctx.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180)
        ctx.fillText(this.letter, 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(-this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.translate(-this.x, -this.y)
    }

    this.update = function() {
        if (working_factor.space_typed) {
            working_factor.space_needed = false;
            if (this.x - this.basex < 0.1 && this.y - this.basey < 0.1 && this.rotation < 0.1) {
                working_factor.space_typed = false;
            } else {
                this.velocity.x = (this.basex - this.x) / 20;
                this.velocity.y = (this.basey - this.y) / 20;
                this.drotate = -this.rotation / 20;
                this.x += this.velocity.x;
                this.y += this.velocity.y;
                this.rotation += this.drotate;
            }
        } else {
            if (distance(this.x, this.y, mouse.x, mouse.y) < 50) {
                working_factor.space_needed = true;
                this.velocity.x = (mouse.x - mouse.prevX) / mouse.dt * velocity
                this.velocity.y = (mouse.y - mouse.prevY) / mouse.dt * velocity
                this.drotate = Math.random() * angular_velocity;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
                if (this === particles[i]) continue;
                if (distance(this.x, this.y, particles[i].x, particles[i].y) < 120) {
                    resolveCollision(this, particles[i])
                }
            }


            if (this.x - 100 < 0 || this.x + 100 > window.innerWidth) {
                this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x;
                this.d2x = -this.d2x;
            }
            if (this.y - 100 < 0 || this.y + 100 > window.innerHeight) {
                this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y;
                this.d2y = -this.d2y;
            }
            this.x += this.velocity.x;
            this.y += this.velocity.y;
            this.rotation += this.drotate;
            this.ddrotate = (this.drotate - 0) / 20;
            this.drotate -= this.ddrotate;
            this.d2x = (this.velocity.x - 0) / 10
            this.d2y = (this.velocity.y - 0) / 10
            this.velocity.x -= this.d2x;
            this.velocity.y -= this.d2y;
        }
        this.draw();
    }

}

//Init Function.
function init() {
    particles = [new Particle('L', window.innerWidth / 2 - gap * 3 + 2.5, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('e', window.innerWidth / 2 - gap * 2 + 5, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('i', window.innerWidth / 2 - gap - 4.5, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('b', window.innerWidth / 2 - 7.5, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('T', window.innerWidth / 2 + gap - 2.5, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('o', window.innerWidth / 2 + 2 * gap + 1, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap), new Particle('n', window.innerWidth / 2 + 3 * gap + 2, window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap)]

}

//Animate Function
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        particles[i].update();
    }
    writeHeading();
    if (working_factor.space_needed)
        writeJumble();
}

//Event Listeners
//Click Event Listener
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    if (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2 > 14.5 && e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2 < 205.5 && e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap > -25 && e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap < 10) {
        window.open("/about.html", "_self")
    }
})

//Space Event Listener
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.key === " ") {
        e.preventDefault();
        working_factor.space_typed = true;
    }
})

//Mouse movement Event Listener

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var now = Date.now()
    mouse.prevX = mouse.x;
    mouse.prevY = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
    mouse.dt = now - mouse.timestamp;
    mouse.timestamp = now;
    if (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2 > 14.5 && e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2 < 205.5 && e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap > -25 && e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2 - vGap < 10) {
        canvas.style.cursor = "pointer"
    } else {
        canvas.style.cursor = "auto"
    }
})

//When Loaded.
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    init();
    animate();
})


//When resized.
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 5;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 5;
    init();
})
```

Comment: I have tried your site on both Chrome and Firefox on Windows10 and they both work the same - the characters do not go to the top. What system are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth, I am using Ubuntu20.